# Walking Autodesk Desktop Connector - BIM 360 and 360 Team folders

Tags: revit-api, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

is there any API to retrieve all files/folders in BIM 360 & BIM 360 Team network drives on desktop? I tried different cmd and python approaches (e.g. os.walk) but they only list folder that users have manually opened (e.g. folders/subfolders/files are being listed with queries only after I double-click and open them manually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No API for Desktop Connector at a moment. You will need to use Forge Data Management API.

```
e.g., https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels 
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/
```